# What is the type of setContentView()

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding, setcontentview

Please check the Edit.

```
   val binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this@MainActivity,R.layout.activity_main)
```

I am getting the below error pointing to `setConentView()`

Type interface failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in

```
fun <T: ViewDataFinding!> setContentView(activity:Activity!, layoutId:Int):T!
```

please specify it explicitly.

**Edit:**

so According to [android documentation](https://tldrify.com/ngy) , its return type will be MainActivityBinding. But when I am adding required changes

val binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this@MainActivity,R.layout.activity_main)

I am getting the error

```
 Error:(21, 15) error: cannot find symbol class MainActivityBinding
```

Comment: Are you using kotlin? `this@MainActivity` is kotlin syntax , for java `MainActivity.this`

Comment: yes I am using kotlin.@Sanoop

Comment: [This](https://github.com/svenjacobs/android-best-practices/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/svenjacobs/abp/app/databinding/DataBindingActivity.kt) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
val binding: MainActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

or

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<MainActivityBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: unresolved references at MainActivityBinding @maphongba008

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal That should be `ActivityMainBinding` as your layout name is `activity_main.xml`

Comment: as @Ravi mentioned, this depends on you layout name, MainActivityBinding is just an example

Comment: As @RaviRupareliya suggests it should be upper Camel Case of layout file name. But Still I am getting the error unresolved references

Answer (score -1):

There are only three version of setContentView in android

- void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
- void setContentView(View view)
- void setContentView(int layoutResID)

the version of setContentView you are using is undefined.

Comment: I am using the data-binding, in this, I have to pass the type of setcontentView which is UpperCamelCase of the layout file. Please have a look at data binding.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question and doesn't take into account databinding.